# Facebook Ads Api: Can you Get Timeseries of CPI in 15 minutes intervals?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I've just started playing with API's for the first time and my first attempt is with the facebook ads api. I'm looking through the documentation and can see how to pull all cost per action data. Right now I'm really interested in CPI (Cost Per Install) data for a specific campaign, ad set and ad in 15 minute intervals.

Does anyone know if this is even possible with the current API?

Comment: 15 minute intervals, no, hourly is the minimum interval we provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get reporting stats through the Ads Insights Api: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.5

As you mentioned, you can get Cost Per Install data by requesting the `cost_per_action_type` field in your request.

For instance, a call to `v2.5/<AD_SET_ID>/insights?fields=['cost_per_action_type']`

Would have the cost of mobile app installs as part of the response

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "cost_per_action_type": [
       {
         "action_type": "mobile_app_install",
         "value": ...
       }
    ],
    "date_start": ...,
    "date_stop": ...
  }
}
```

You can make api calls at your discretion as long as you're within the api rate limits: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting

Comment: This is as far as I got. But I couldn't find the specific call to only pull the mobile app install  data. It gave me an array  of all the actions.

Comment: you have to pull all actions and then filter yourself in code unfortunately